# MIPS loading values from address

Tags: assembly, memory, mips, memory-address

I am learning MIPS Assembly language and I was wondering how I can load values from an address. For example I want to store the memory address 0x10010000 in $t2.
0x10010000 has in it values 12,33,70,70(0x10010000 - 0x10010003).
0x10010004 would have something like F4,A6, 12,99((0x10010004 - 0x10010007).

I have this so far

```
add $t3, $t2, $zero
lw $t4, 0($t3)
add $t5, $t4, -6
sw $t5, 4($t2)
```

but don't know how I would "initialize" $t2

Comment: put a label on your data, and use `la $t2, labelName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a label on your data, and use `la $t2, labelName`.

Alternately you can load `0x10010000` into `$t2` using `lui`, which loads 16-bits worth of constant into the upper part of the registers — here you'd use `lui $t2, 0x1001`.

If you needed non-zero for the low 16 bits (as in, say, for `0x10010400`), you finish them after the `lui` with an `ori` (e.g. `ori $t2, $t2, 0x0400`).

Also, `la` is a pseudo instruction.  It will generally expand into two instructions, and, you'll be able to see that when you assemble your code (e.g. in MARS or QtSPIM).